# IPBoard password hashing issue, doesn't match algorithm

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc, ipb

A quick link to the IPBoard page explaining that the forum uses the standard `md5(md5($salt).md5($password))` format that most forums use can be found here: https://www.invisionpower.com/support/guides/_/advanced-and-developers/miscellaneous/passwords-in-ipboard-r130

I actually come from using MyBB which uses the same structure, so I would have thought just changing the table/column names in my query would make for a relatively simple switch, boy was I wrong.

The original query that I had used was the following

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_members` WHERE `name`=? AND `members_pass_hash`= MD5(CONCAT(MD5(members_pass_salt), MD5(?)))"
```

This is a prepared statement, in which the username and the raw password are provided by my server. This unfortunately was not working, I took a few steps and started to debug the data, instead of using the SQL MD5 function I grabbed the data and performed MD5 checks in Java to get a better idea of what was going on.

To do this, I used the following MD5 function I've used for a long time:

```
public String MD5(String md5) {
           try {
                java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                  sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
               }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This yielded some slightly strange results, in which the data wasn't matching up.

```
Database salt: *nzFC 
Database hash: 6bac5cba673134ea084e481b57921134
Server generated hash: d7f94e3f262e7dee81b12ac087c42b18
```

The server generated has was generated by using the `MD5(MD5(salt) + MD5(rawpassword))` method the other forums use, including IPB. This worked on MyBB, so I'm a bit flustered.

I've checked for things such as capitalization problems, etc, but I'm coming up absolutely blank.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to something wrong with either the password or salt your using. In the following examples, I used the salt `363` and password `password`.

If [run this code in Java](http://ideone.com/GtdWbu):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String salt = "363";
        String password = "password";
        String md5 = MD5(MD5(salt) + MD5(password));

        System.out.println("MD5: " + md5);
    }

    public static String MD5(String md5) {
           try {
                java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                  sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
               }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            }
            return null;
    }
}
```

I get:

> MD5: 81a40e9a2b5b97d2ecc28c26cd2d62f4

If I execute this in MySQL, I get the same MD5 hash:

```
> SELECT MD5(CONCAT(MD5('363'),MD5('password')));
+-----------------------------------------+
| MD5(CONCAT(MD5('363'),MD5('password'))) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 81a40e9a2b5b97d2ecc28c26cd2d62f4        |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You have `Database salt` mentioned, so maybe your using the database salt when in fact each user has its own unique salt?

Comment: That's correct, each user has it's own unique salt, also, issueing the command in SQL results in : "2565f194634d1903e185202fab587ef9" which is a completely different hash.

`SELECT MD5(CONCAT(MD5(members_pass_salt),MD5(members_pass_salt))) FROM `oblivion_server`.`forum_members` WHERE `member_id`='1'`

Comment: That query is incorrect. You have the column ``members_pass_salt`` in there twice. The second should be the raw password.

Comment: Besides the salt and password being wrong, I'm not sure what else the problem could be. You should be able to get some help from the [IPB Forums](http://community.invisionpower.com/)

Comment: It was entity encoding that was the problem.